# Marketo Munchkin API strange response

Tags: marketo

I'm working with the Marketo Munchkin API.  I can run an associateLead function, but I don't see the lead in the lead database, and I'm get a strange HTTP response to that request:

[image]

A GIF image?  That's what it looks like.  Why I am getting this?  Or, how can I confirm that the request was successful?

Also, this may be related.  In my Munchkin init code in the `<head>`, I added a console.log line in the onreadystatechange callback, but it never fires:

```
s.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log('ready_state_change');
  if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
    initMunchkin();
  }
};
```

So maybe it's not initializing properly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with the Munchkin API, since most Marketo customers use either the Forms 2.0 API or the REST API. However, it looks like the Munchkin itself is loading fine, because I see "visitWebPage" is requested. That's a sign that Munchkin is correctly initialized. Did you enable Munchkin API in Admin > Munchkin in the Marketo UI? Did you correctly generate the SHA1 has as described here http://developers.marketo.com/javascript-api/lead-tracking/api-reference/#munchkin_associatelead?